# Checking the antipode for the dual of the Group Hopf Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups

Consider the vector space $\mathbb{C}G\,=\left\{ f:\,G\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}\right\}$ , and define the following

- multiplication: $\mu\left(f\otimes
     g\right)\left(x\right):=f\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)$,
- co-multiplication: $\triangle\left(f\right)\left(x\otimes   
     y\right)\,:=f\left(xy\right)$,
- unit: $\eta\left(x\right):=1_{G}$,
- co-unit: $\epsilon\left(f\right)\,:=f\left(1_{G}\right)$,
- antipode: $S\left(f\right)\left(x\right):=f\left(x^{-1}\right)$.

It is well known it is a Hopf Algebra (look at the [second example on Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_algebra#Examples)). Anyway I'm trying to demonstrate that is valid the relation for the antipode 
$$\mu\circ\left(S\otimes id\right)\circ\triangle=\eta\circ\varepsilon=\mu\circ\left(id\otimes S\right)\circ\triangle,$$
and I'm getting quite confused on how should I proceed since it result to me that
$$\left(\mu\circ\left(S\otimes id\right)\circ\triangle\left(f\right)\right)\left(x\otimes y\right)=f\left(x^{-1}y\right)\neq f\left(xy^{-1}\right)$$ 
Can anybody write che proof explicitly or at least give me an hint on how to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I write $f = \sum \lambda_g \delta_g$, and compute $\eta \circ \varepsilon (f) = \eta(\lambda_1) = \lambda_1 (\sum_g \delta_g)$.

Now $\Delta(f) = \sum_{g,h} \lambda_g \delta_h \otimes \delta_{h^{-1}g}$ so $((S \otimes id) \circ \Delta )(f) = \sum_{g,h} \lambda_g \delta_{h^{-1}} \otimes \delta_{h^{-1}g}$.

Finally $\mu \circ (S \otimes id) \circ \Delta(f) = \sum_{g,h} \lambda_g \delta_{h^{-1}}\delta_{h^{-1}g} = \lambda_1 (\sum_g \delta_g)$

Comment: For clarity: $\delta_g \delta_h =\delta_g$ if $g = h$, and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: I also tried your approach and in my calculation I mismatched the indices of the co-multplication, now it makes sense thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Write $A$ for your Hopf algebra, and $k={\mathbb C}$, and $e$ for the identity element of $G$.

For clarity, let's view $A$ only using the RHS of your definition - namely, as $k$-valued functions on $G$, and denote by  $\delta\in A$ for the function defined by 
$$\delta (g ) = 1\in k\text{, for all $g\in G$.}$$

We have

- $\varepsilon \colon A \to k$ is evaluation at $e$: $$\varepsilon a  = a( e).$$
- $\eta \colon k \to A$, with $\eta (z ) = z\delta$, for $z\in k$.
- Therefore, one has $\eta \circ \varepsilon \colon A \to A$, with 
  $$\left[(\eta\circ \varepsilon) (a )\right] (g) = a(e) \delta (g) =a(e).$$

On the other hand,

- $\Delta\colon A \to A\otimes A$. The algebra $A\otimes A$ is the set of $k$-valued functions on $G\times G$, and  $(\Delta a) (g, h) = a ( gh ).$
  (Your evaluation of the tensor product $x\otimes y$ didn't make sense, and I think that is part of the confusion in your attempt to prove the equality.)

  - $\mu (a \otimes b ) (g) = a ( g ) b ( g)$. In other words, $\mu$ is the dual to the diagonal map $G \to G \times G$.

Your equality (to be proved)
$$ \mu\circ\left(S\otimes id\right)\circ\triangle=\eta\circ\varepsilon=\mu\circ\left(id\otimes S\right)\circ\triangle$$
is an equality of $A\to A$ maps - i.e., we should evaluate both sides on an arbitrary element $a \in A$, and see that the result is the same function on $G$.

So, if $a\in A$, and $g\in G$, you want to test the value  (in $k$) of 
$$ \left[(\mu\circ\left(S\otimes id\right)\circ\triangle) (a) \right] (g) $$

Running through the definitions, we get that that is equal to

$$ \left[(( S \otimes id )\circ \triangle ) (a )\right] ( g, g ) =\triangle (a) ( g^{-1},g ) = a ( g^{-1} g) = a(e).$$

*Edit/Addendum*

As requested, here is a clarification (I hope!) of 'Running through the definitions':

First of all, it might be worthwhile to repeat the above 'dual to diagonal' (maybe 'transpose' would have been a better word than 'dual') statement for $\mu$. Identify $A\otimes A$ with the $k$-valued functions on $G \times G$. Then, if $c\in A\otimes A$, we have, by duality/transpose, i.e., by definition after the identification of $A\otimes A$ with functions on $G \times G$, that
 $$\mu (c ) (g) = c (g,g ).$$

Next, set  $\phi= \left(S\otimes id\right)\circ\triangle $.

Then 
$$ (\mu\circ\left(S\otimes id\right)\circ\triangle) (a) = (\mu \circ \phi ) ( a )  = \mu ( \phi ( a ) ).$$

Therefore, by the previous observation, $$ \mu (\phi ( a ) ) ( g ) = \phi (a ) ( g, g).$$
(Note that $\phi : A \to A\otimes A$, so the evaluation of $\phi(a)$ on $(g,g)$ makes sense.)

Similarly, $$\phi ( a ) = (\  \left(S\otimes id\right)\circ\triangle\  ) (a ) = \left(S\otimes id\right) ( \triangle (a ) ).$$
Therefore 
$$ \phi(a) (g,g) = (\triangle (a ) ) (g^{-1}, g).$$
This last is equal to 
$ a ( g^{-1}g ) = a (e ) $.

Comment: A different take from that in Nicolas's (fine) answer... N.B. I wrote $a$ for your $f$ to emphasize that $a\in A$. My $\delta$ is his $\sum \delta_g$.

Comment: I considered should be something like your last sentence but my problem was "running to the definitions" and getting your last sentence. For example why do you use $(g,g,)$ as argument and not $(g,h)$ since a priori the function is defined for every $(g,h)$? Can you explain a little bette how to get to your last equation?

Comment: Your 'a priori' (in your comment) isn't right... By defintion $$ \left[(\mu\circ\left(S\otimes id\right)\circ\triangle) (a) \right] (g) = \left[( S \otimes id ) \triangle ) (a )\right] ( g, g ).$$

Comment: @Dac0 - do you see?

Comment: I don't understand exactly that part... why you're susbtituting the multiplication  with an evaluation on $(g,g)$... what definitions are you using? I guess the dual of the coproduct on the group algebra... but I'm getting confused in that step, also because I don't get why do you start with the multiplication

Comment: please can you edit your answer doing a step by step on that part?

Comment: The map $\mu$ takes $A\otimes A$  to $A$. That is, it takes functions on  $G\times G$ to functions on $G$. That is: if $c$ is a function on $G \times G$, $\mu(c) $ is a function on $G$. By definition $\mu (c) (g ) = c (g,g)$.  OK?

Comment: Namely, there isn't much step to do there - it follows by definition.

Comment: If you're still unhappy about this, I'll try to come back to this over the weekend - it's kind of late here in my time zone. Good night!

Comment: Let's say it is ok, but why are you applying the multiplication as first while it should be as last and co-multiplication as first? Yes please your approach was much close to what I wanted to do but still the problems I had are unsolved... I think there's just a misinterpretation from my part of some basic definition

Comment: @Dac0 : I added an 'addendum'. I hope it helps...

Comment: @Dac0: I guess it didn't help! The point is the idea/observation (standard in algebraic geometry) that if $\phi \colon X \to Y$, and, $f$ a function on $Y$, then $f\circ \phi$ is a function on $X$. Therefore, if we set $R$ the functions on $Y$, and $S$ the functions on $X$, we get a 'pullback' (ring homomorphism) $\phi^*\colon R \to S$, which is defined by $\phi^*(f) = f\circ \phi$. In our situation, if $i$ is the diagonal map $g \mapsto (g,g)$, then $\mu = i^*$: i.e., $\mu (c) = c \circ i$. Is that clear? Does that clarify? It's worth understanding...

Comment: Yes thank you... I just didn't see the update, now I upvoted your answer